# Parse Issue empty objects when save Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, parse-platform

I have a strange issue when I use Parse .save method.
It's pretty simple when I save Objects that work well. When I save Array of strings that work too. But when I try to save Array of Object like: [{"pos": 10101, "id": 2312}, {...}, {...}]

The save work but when I check my database I have a Array with empty objects.

Someone already had the problem before?

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save dictionaries to Parse. You'll have to structure your data differently. You can save an array of array's but not [{"blue": "sky"}] or ["blue" : "sky"].

Comment: Thank's for the answer.